# Using pandas to create pivot table builder in Python

Tags: python, pivot-table, spyder

I am attempting to write a code using pandas that creates pivot tables to a user defined spec where the inputs from the user will be given in a web based application made using flask.

I am currently trying to use a format such as this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_csv("MyData.csv")
file.head()

def pivot(file):

    table = pd.pivot_table(data,index=["Variable1","Variable2"])

    return
```

Where I think a pivot table will be produced with Variable1 and Variable2 as indexes.

How can I write a function where the structure of the pivot table is determined by inputs from the user through the above described application instead of being manually written into the code itself?

Comment: How about passing the list of indices as a parameter to the pivot function? You can ask for user input using the input functionality in python.